# Select unique value pairs that occur (count) more than once inside a table

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

How can I retrieve an row with unique value pairs that occur more than once...
Heres an example of what I'm what I am trying to..

```
SELECT 
 column_fk_id1, column_fk_id2,
 COUNT(distinct column_fk_id1, column_fk_id2) AS unique_pair_repeats
FROM table
WHERE column_fk_id1 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY column_fk_id1, column_fk_id2
HAVING unique_pair_repeats > 2
```

Comment: What's "Msql"? What DBMS are you using? Sample data and expected output?

Comment: Does "MSQL" mean "MS SQL Server" or "MySQL"?

Comment: Took a not so wild guess and added the MySQL tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have almost works, just remove the distinct and change the > 2 to > 1.  The distinct is not necessary as the grouping handles that and the > 2 is looking for things that have at least three entries rather than just two.

```
drop table tab1;
create table tab1 as (select 1 column_fk_id1,2 column_fk_id2 from dual);
insert into tab1 values (1,2);
insert into tab1 values (2,1);
insert into tab1 values (3,4);
insert into tab1 values (4,3);
insert into tab1 values (5,5);
insert into tab1 values (6,7);
insert into tab1 values (6,7);
insert into tab1 values (6,8);
commit;


SELECT column_fk_id1, column_fk_id2, COUNT(*) AS unique_pair_repeats
FROM tab1
WHERE column_fk_id1 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY column_fk_id1, column_fk_id2
HAVING count(*) > 1;

COLUMN_FK_ID1 COLUMN_FK_ID2 UNIQUE_PAIR_REPEATS
------------- ------------- -------------------
            1             2                   2
            6             7                   2

2 rows selected.
```